# How to preload a UIWebView in another ViewController when launching the application in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, webview, uiwebview

I am actually using two WebViews in my iOS application. I want to preload the second WebView in my SecondViewController when launching the application. I've tried to preload the WebView using NSNotification Center but it does not work. How can I preload the WebView in the SecondViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in the following way:

1. Preload a view controller which contains a webview and store a reference in Appdelegate.
2. Call self.preloadvc?.view.layoutSubviews() in AppDelegate
3. At any time needed you can present it.

It seems necessary to create the web view programmatically in the view controller

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

//
var preloadvc : PreloadVC? = nil
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            //Preloading
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.preloadvc = PreloadVC()
                    //Thats the trick for preloading the view
                    self.preloadvc?.view.layoutSubviews()
                })
    return true
}
```

}

```
class PreloadVC : UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
var mypreloadedView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mypreloadedView = UIWebView(frame: view.frame)
    view.addSubview(mypreloadedView)
    mypreloadedView.delegate = self
    if let myurl = URL(string: "https://www.google.de") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: myurl)
        self.mypreloadedView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    print("Loaded")
}
```

}

Presentation anywhere :

```
@IBAction func ShowPreloaded(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    if let preloadedvc = appDelegate.preloadvc {
        self.present(preloadedvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```